# Next.js When Link to external page it similar to the component will not unmount only for IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, next.js, react-router

Next.js When Linked to an external page it is similar to the component that will not unmount on the page in our app it will occur only for IOS
I already set the box on the top left when clicking It will change the state of color

This one I click box 1 it will go to the linking URL

[image: 1]

If I go back to the previous website It needs to reset all states to the default right?
but in IOS it seems like not reset the state to the default so what should I handle in this case

When going back it will still change the border color

[image: 2]

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useState } from 'react';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
export default function Home() {
  const [color, setcolor] = useState('#fff');
  const a= ()=>{
    setcolor("orange")
  }
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>
          Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a>
        </h1>

        <p className={styles.description}>
          Get started by editing{' '}
          <code className={styles.code}>pages/index.js</code>
        </p>

        <div className={styles.grid}>
          <a href="https://nextjs.org/docs" onClick={a} className={styles.card} style={{borderColor:color}}>
            <h2>Documentation &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Find in-depth information about Next.js features and API.</p>
          </a>

          <a href="https://nextjs.org/learn" className={styles.card} style={{borderColor:color}}>
            <h2>Learn &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Learn about Next.js in an interactive course with quizzes!</p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples"
            className={styles.card}
            style={{borderColor:color}}
          >
            <h2>Examples &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Discover and deploy boilerplate example Next.js projects.</p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://vercel.com/new?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            className={styles.card} style={{borderColor:color}}
          >
            
            <h2>Deploy &rarr;</h2>
            <p>
              Instantly deploy your Next.js site to a public URL with Vercel.
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </main>

      <footer className={styles.footer}>
        <a
          href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Powered by{' '}
          <span className={styles.logo}>
            <Image src="/vercel.svg" alt="Vercel Logo" width={72} height={16} />
          </span>
        </a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: @vimuth
 Thank you for helping and making it better to see the image.

Comment: @vimuth I ask a question to confuse or not clear?